# Rating system for 2 vs 2, 2 vs 1 and 1 vs 1 game

Tags: statistics, algorithms, scoring-algorithm

We play football table in such configurations:

- 2 vs 2 players
- 2 vs 1
- 1 vs 1

Team (consisting of 1 or 2 players) wins the single game when they score 10th goal.

I would like to introduce a rating system for individual players only. Teams are volatile, people freely pair with others, just depends who is near the table and who wants to play.

I've read about [Elo rating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system), but it was designed for 1 vs 1 games, in which you can either win, draw or lose.

In table football we have different players configurations and 20 different game outcomes: Winning 10:0, 10:1, ...,  10:9. Losing 0:10, 1:10, ..., 9:10. No draws.

It could be made that we treat it like chess, i.e. only win or loss, but I think we drop too much information in such approach. Winning 10:0 is far better than winning 10:9.

Can you propose a rating system dedicated for described table football game?

Comment: One easy way would be to use ELO and interpret the ending score as a best of 19 games, so that a 10-6 victory is entered into the rating as ten victories and six losses.

Comment: Do you want to get a rating for each player or for each team?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi For each player only. Teams are very dynamic, people freely pair (or don't) with others, just depends who is near the table and who wants to play.

Comment: If you're interested in use (more than in development), you should give a try to [rankade](https://rankade.com), our ranking system. Rankade can manage any kind of match (one-on-one, faction vs. faction (two teams, which may be asymmetrical, and more)). We host many foosball groups/clubs, as well as other sports/games ones (here's our [dojo](https://rankade.com/dojo)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a proposition, maybe you can find some weak points in it:

It's based on Elo. First, all the players get 1000 rating points ($R$). Let's focus on 1 vs 1, in the end I will show how to deal with 2 vs 1 and 2 vs 2. Player's A expected score $E_A$ is calculated as follows:

$$ E_A = \frac{1}{1+10^{(R_B - R_A)/500}} \in (0, 1)$$

Where $R_A$ is a point rating for player A. Player's B expected rating is $E_B = 1 - E_A$.

New rating for player A:

$$R_A' = R_A + 100(S_A - E_A)$$

Where $S_A$ is the actual score. In case of winning $10:i$ $(i \in {0, 1, ..., 9}$) it is<sup>1</sup>:

$$S_A = \frac{10}{10+i}$$

In case of losing $i:10$ it is:

$$S_A = 1-\frac{10}{10+i}$$

Example:

Player A with $R_A = 1000$ points won 10:6 with player B with $R_B = 1000$ points. In such case, expected score $E_A = E_B = 0.5$. Actual score $S_A$ for player A is $\frac{10}{10 + 6}=0.625$. So, $R_A' = 1000 + 100(0.625 - 0.5) = 1000 + 12.5 = 1012.5$, $R_B' = 1000 - 12.5 = 987.5$.

What to do with 2 players A and B in one team playing versus player C? We can treat player A and B as one player with rating $\frac{R_A + R_B}{2}$. So, $E_A = E_B = \frac{1}{1+10^{(R_C - \frac{R_A + R_B}{2})/500}}$. New rating will be calculated individually:
$$R_A' = R_A + 100(S_{AB} - E_A), R_B' = R_B + 100(S_{AB} - E_B)$$

$S_{AB}$ is the actual game score for player A and B. Since $E_A = E_B$, rating change for players in the same team is the same.

2 vs 2 case analogically.

---

<sup>1</sup>Why $S_A = \frac{10}{10+i}$?

Consider a winning $10 : i$. Let $p$ be the probability of the winning team scoring a goal. This will be our "actual score (performance)". Let's assume that this probability is constant for the whole game. After seeing the actual outcome, $10 : i$, we can ask: what's the most likely $p$? One can use [maximum likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation). What's the probability that it was $10:i$, given that the probability of the winning team scoring a goal was $p$? It is:

$P(10:i | p) = \binom{9+i}{9}p^{10} (1-p)^i$

There were $10 + i$ goals in total. The last one belong to the winning team, it was their 10th goal, so this one is pinned. $\binom{9+i}{9}$ is the number of 9 winners goals and $i$ losers goals combinations. Multiplied by the probability of winners scoring 10 goals, $p^{10}$.
Multiplied by the probability of losers scoring $i$ goals, $(1-p)^i$. Their goals positions are already determined, so no combinations here.

Now we just need to find which $p$ maximizes $P(10:i | p)$. One could just take the first derivative and set it to zero. However, the maximum is the same for $\log P(10:i | p)$ and it will be easier to find maximum for it, for log-likelihood:

$\log P(10:i | p) = \log \binom{9+i}{9} + \log p^{10} + \log (1-p)^i = \log \binom{9+i}{9} + 10 \log p + i \log (1-p)$

Set first derivative of $P$ with respect to $p$ to 0:

$\log P(10:i | p)' = \frac{10}{p} + \frac{i}{p-1} = 0$

$\frac{10(p-1) + ip}{p(p-1)} = 0$

$10p-10 + ip = 0$

$p(10+i) = 10$

$p = \frac{10}{10+i}$